# Extract text and from an array

Tags: php

I have a string :

```
$string='{"person":
                [
                 "name":{"first":"Jhon","last":"Ramos"},
                 "phones":{"cel1":"809-555-4444","cel2":"809-444-           4444","home":"819-515-4434"},
                 "address":{"addr1":"adress numer one","addr2":"adress number two"}
                ]
 }';
```

I want to parse the string using json and print the names of all sub-arrays like : 
name
phones
address

just the name, not values.

How can I do that?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is not a valid json.

Comment: Replace your  [ ] inside person for {} and that will be a valid JSON. Next time try to validate it using http://jsonlint.com/ or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Use json_decode:

```
$string = '{"person":
            [
             "name":{"first":"Jhon","last":"Ramos"},
             "phones":{"cel1":"809-555-4444","cel2":"809-444-           4444","home":"819-515-4434"},
             "address":{"addr1":"adress numer one","addr2":"adress number two"}
            ]
}';

$result = json_decode($string, true);

foreach($result['person'] as $key => $val)
{
  print_r($val);
}
```

Comment: it arrows : PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in /var/www/person.php on line 16

Comment: Yes because your json is not valid. Check here if your json is valid http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I checked the lson string in the sujested link and i said Ok. but still has error : root@raspberrypi:/var/www# php person.php
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in /var/www/person.php on line 16

Comment: the string look like this :       $string='{"person":
                    [
                     {"name":{"first":"Jhon","last":"Ramos"}},
                     {"phones":{"cel1":"809-555-4444","cel2":"809-444-4444","home":"819-515-4434"}},
                     {"address":{"addr1":"adress numer one","addr2":"adress number two"}}
                    ]
}';

Answer (score 0):

your $string is not a json, so you have to trans it to json with `$string = str_replace(array("[", "]"), array("{", "}"), $string);`

then code as,

```
 <?php
        $string='{"person":
                        [
                         "name":{"first":"Jhon","last":"Ramos"},
                         "phones":{"cel1":"809-555-4444","cel2":"809-444-           4444","home":"819-515-4434"},
                         "address":{"addr1":"adress numer one","addr2":"adress number two"}
                        ]
         }';

         $string = str_replace(array("[", "]"), array("{", "}"), $string);
         $json = json_decode($string, true);
         foreach($json["person"]  as $key => $value)
            echo $key."\n";
    ?>
```

output as,

```
name
phones
address
```